# Apache Commons Email in Jboss send bad html email

Tags: java, apache-commons-email, jboss-4.0.x

Given the following snippet of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
    email.addTo("me@gmail.com", "Manuel");
    email.setFrom("me@gmail.com");
    email.setSubject("daje mpo");
    email.setContent("<html><body>22dlkjalskdj <strong>strong</strong><em>em</em><br>aslkdjsal</body></html>", "text/html");
    email.setAuthentication("me@gmail.com", "mypassword");
    email.setDebug(true);
    email.setSSL(true);
    email.setTLS(true);
    String s = email.send();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

When I execute this piece of code in Eclipse, I receive an email like:

[image: correct email]

That is what I want!

But then, I tried to use this `main` inside my application deployed in Jboss-4.0.5, I receive an email like this:

[image: wrong email]

So not only the message isn't an *html* message, but also the **subject** of the email was lost, and it seems that instead of send the email with the **to** receiver it uses a **bcc**.
I don't have any idea of what can be the cause of this behavior, can someone help me, or just give me some hint.

**UPDATE**

I notice that when I execute that code "inside" JBoss it doesn't send any headers of the mail message, while executing the same code "inside" Eclipse send the correct message...
I tried to remove all the mail jars in JBoss but it still act this way...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
...
```

no matter what you're actual problem is.

[Sending HTML formatted email](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html)